# Microservices and messaging

Tags: microservices, messaging

I'm in the process of restructuring my first application to use microservices and messaging using an event driven architecture. I will have a content microservice to retrieve content from various sources and add to a message queue for processing. My query is that should the content microservice store the content in its own database as well or is that redundant as I am using messaging?

Comment: Why would it need to store locally? What difference would is make?

Comment: Just thinking if there are any issues and I need to reprocess content. Looking for best practice here as originally the content was stored in the DB.

Comment: As far as best practices concern, it really depends on your case. But if you can just process "as it comes" and not store anything locally, it will be easier to maintain. On the other hand, if you must worry about failures, then some form of storage may be needed, just to keep track of what was processed and what was not.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your design , but any microservice should autonomous,  so it should keep it's own logic and data.

keeping data depends also if you will log something in case of failure or even if you will implement your own retry mechanism